# Indian Movie Database?

Tags: data-request, film, india

Is there any open movie database containing all the Indian movie information which can be used commercially.
I know there are certain providers like http://www.themoviedb.org/ and IMDB where you can scrape or access API.I need to if there is any other choice?

Answer (score 4):

Hmm I don't know if you could find something for a commercial use. But here are a few suggestions.

1) [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware) if you do not want to play with api, you can download all the database. But not for commercial use.

2) An alternative api for movie database [rotten tomatoes](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/Home)

3) An alternative api for movie database [anditson](http://www.anditson.com)

Since you need a commercial use, read very well all the term of uses, just to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Try [Cinemalytics - The Bollywood Movie Database](http://www.cinemalytics.com). They provide free RESTful APIs to access database. This can be used for commercial use as well.