# Open Source alternative to IMDB

Tags: data-request, film

Does anyone know of such a thing? I urgently need a database of all the movies and I want it to be free.

Comment: You will find the same answer in this question http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/indian-movie-database

Comment: Noteworthy movies tend to have Wikipedia entries.

Answer (score 16):

Sadly, [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/film/film) has been [made "read only" March 31st 2015](https://plus.google.com/109936836907132434202/posts/3aYFVNf92A1).

Alternatives are:

- **https://www.themoviedb.org/**
  Actively maintained by a large community and used by [a broad range of apps](https://www.themoviedb.org/apps) under [a propriatary license that states free use](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/terms-of-use):

  > TMDb is committed to free and open access to our APIs for commercial and non-commercial purposes. However, providing the APIs does have real costs for TMDb. For uses of TMDb APIs over a certain rate or for certain types of commercial applications, TMDb reserves the right to charge fees for future use of or access to the TMDb APIs.
- **http://www.omdbapi.com/**
  Run by Brian Fritz under a [CC-BY 4.0 licence](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/).

  > The OMDb API is a free web service to obtain movie information, all content and images on the site are contributed and maintained by our users.

Comment: OMDb just started charging for access to their database. While all the content is still freely licensed, you have to pay $1/month for API access and they have completely dropped the monthly dumps due to DMCA takedowns.

Comment: @ZellFaze There's a new API to get movie details from IMDB. Check this out http://github.com/theapache64/movie_db

Answer (score 10):

Wikidata has an increasingly complete coverage of many topics, including movies

Here's a [sample query to get title](http://tinyurl.com/gw8kzch).

[image]

Use the query builder (top right) to see what data is available.

[image]

*[(my source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32179450/2327328)*

Answer (score 7):

Also, the API at [The Movie Database](http://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api) looks great. It is less clean than IMBD, but it is open and free for use.

Edit: [this metastor repository has a dump of TMB](http://mx.daviesinc.com/qwait/metastor/tree/461fd9f85bc0d59188913bcee544575e998ef10d/metadata)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the licensing but it's at least called a "free"base:

http://www.freebase.com/film/film

Comment: "The Freebase API will be completely shut-down on Aug 31 2016."

Answer (score 0):

Found another source in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/73jf0p/since_omdb_went_private_a_few_months_ago_i/) discussion.
Don't know much about it tho.

Address is: [`https://voku.xyz/imdb`](https://voku.xyz/imdb).

Comment: This is not an alternative to IMDB, it's just a site that let's your query IMDB

Comment: I'm still gonna leave my answer here for the reference.

Comment: naturally, link is now broken. a site that would allow to query IMDb would still be an alternative because it would need its own dataset for doing it so.