# Public database of book titles?

Tags: data-request, api, books

I want my users to set their previously read books in my app.

Is there any database with easily accessible API where I can get up-to-date book titles?

Comment: The movies part of your question would be a duplicate of http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/open-source-alternative-to-imdb so I edit your question to focus on books, hope you are OK with it :-)

Comment: Worldcat.org is one such site /DB.

Comment: because they don't have every book archived. you can join and then add the book to the archive....DO IT!

Comment: we have A LOT of books but not all of them. Our users are constantly adding more items to the database. Hopefully we will succeed to collect all books in the near future.

Comment: @albert EnJayz so both of your database is open for public, user can add records both to your database, do you sync outpan <-> openlibrary back and forth, that would make much sense from user perspective?

Comment: you can propose that to the groups. or sync them yourself

Comment: I found that book :) https://www.outpan.com/view_product.php?barcode=9789630888288

Answer (score 8):

[Open library](https://openlibrary.org/) has a goal of one page for every book, and has the data you seek.
It's run by the internet archive.

Comment: Of note is the fact that openlibrary.org's data is [under](https://openlibrary.org/help/faq/using) a CC0 license.

Answer (score 4):

The British Library has a Linked Data API to the British National Bibliography (BNB): http://www.bl.uk/bibliographic/datafree.html

Examples of how to use the API can be found here:

- [IPython notebook demonstrating how to use the BNB Linked Data API](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/psychemedia/84ee421ffac30fee2ca6)
- [Tutorial - Accessing the British National Bibliography Using SPARQL](http://blog.ldodds.com/2014/10/08/accessing-the-british-national-bibliography-using-sparql/)