# Public International Database of Literature Works?

Tags: database, books, literature

There's a question about books: ([Public database of book titles?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/public-database-of-book-titles)), but what I'm looking for is actually a DB of literature works, not books.

For example, "Romeo and Juliet" is a single literature work, but there are multiple books published with it.

So this is definitely different.

Comment: Try [Wikidata](https://tinyurl.com/yapzso9l).

Comment: Can you add a definition of *literature work* to make the distinction more clear?

Comment: @JanDoggen actually, everything that can be published in books :) Novels, stories, poetry, etc. Writers write literature work and then their work is being published in different books.

Comment: @StanislavKralin thanks, sounds interesting. But how to get authors too? I've added author name in fields, but got significantly less results.

Comment: @GinoPane, uncomment lines 4,5,7 and put lines 4, 5 into `OPTIONAL {...}`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin cool, thank you, that's better: http://tinyurl.com/yagvxmqu

Comment: If that works for you, you can self-answer your question, so that others benefit from it as well (but then, add the query, don't just link elsewhere).

Comment: @GinoPane, or rather [this](https://tinyurl.com/ya6g3ff6).

Comment: @JanDoggen yes, I will, if no more answers come in a couple of days

Comment: @GinoPane, no more answers came in a couple of days...

Comment: @StanislavKralin indeed! I have postponed this again and again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution so far came from comments. Thanks to @StanislavKralin who suggested to use public Wikidata as a source.

Here's the link to SPARQL query that can be tried: http://tinyurl.com/y6wpk5q5.